# Drawing 3D level sets/curves

Tags: multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions, curves

I was asked to

Draw the level sets of $$f(x,y,z) = 9x^2-4y^2-36z$$

I under how to draw them with just two variables, but does anyone have any resources that could help me visualize drawing these sets in 3D? I'm having trouble understanding what the answer would look like

Comment: Could I rewrite the equation so that x = 1/6x^2 - 1/9y^2 and sketch that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is close, though, I presume you mean $z=\ldots$, rather than $x=\ldots$.

Note that a level set of your function has the form $f(x,y,z)=k$ for some real number $k$.  For this particular function, that is
$$9x^2-4y^2-36z = k$$
or
$$z = \frac{9x^2-4y^2}{36}-\frac{k}{36}.$$
Presumably, you know that each of these is a [hyperbolic paraboloid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicParaboloid.html); the parameter $k$ simply shifts the paraboloid up or down.  Here are a few of them sketched together:

[image]

Comment: Okay I'm not sure if I'm supposed to sketch this on a x,y axis or 3D space because idk if I can draw that, but thanks this helps is understanding what I need to do with these types of problems.

Comment: @Josephhooper The level set of a function of $n$ variables lives in $n$-dimensional space - always. For example, the level set of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ is a circle $x^2+y^2=k$ that lives in the plane. The level set of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ is a sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=k$ that lives in space.  You've got $f(x,y,z)=k$ so your level set is a surface that lives in space.